# AutoIt - Microsoft.XMLDOM: Problems writing to XML-file

Tags: xml, autoit

I want to have AutoIt use the Windows API to interact with XML-files on my system.
I manage to load and read from the XML-file quite well, but I am having some issues writing to it.

### AutoIt Script

```
; An object for the XML-file on Windows OS using Microsoft's API.
; @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828(v=vs.85).aspx
$oXML = ObjCreate("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

$oXML.async = False

; Check to see if the XML-file is in place.
; @see https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileExists.htm
If FileExists(@ScriptDir & "\" & "db2.xml") Then
    ; Load the proper XML-file to the XML-object.
    ; @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx
    $oXML.load(@ScriptDir & "\" & "db2.xml")
Else
    ; Create a new XML-file.
    If Not _FileCreate(@ScriptDir & "\" & "db2.xml") Then
        MsgBox(16, "Fatal Error", "Could neither load nor create XML file!")
        Exit
    Else
        ; Load the newly created XML-file to the XML-object.
        ; @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722(v=vs.85).aspx
        $oXML.load(@ScriptDir & "\" & "db2.xml")
    EndIf
EndIf

; Create a node to be written to the XML-object.
; @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757901(v=vs.85).aspx
$current = $oXML.createNode(8, "test", "")

; Save the XML-object to the XML-document.
; @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769(v=vs.85).aspx
$oXML.save(@ScriptDir & "\" & "db2.xml")
```

My XML-file is located in the script directory and is completely empty.
When I run the AutoIt script, I get absolutely no error messages and
when changing focus to the XML-document loaded in Notepad++,
I get the message that the file has recently been modified
by an external program and it asks if I want to reload it.
I do, but the file still appears completely empty.

By my logic, there should be a comment left in the file from the createNode command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a comment use the `createComment`function tho. You have to **get the element** first and **append on the element instead of** doing this on **your XML-Object**.

**test.xml**

```
<test>
</test>
```

**xml.au3**

```
Local $oErrorHandler = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error", "_ErrFunc")
Local $oXML = ObjCreate("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
$oXML.load(@ScriptDir & "\test.xml")
ConsoleWrite("$oXml.ReadyState = " & $oXml.ReadyState & @LF)

Local $oRootElement = $oXML.documentElement
Local $oNewElement = $oXML.createElement("NEW")
$oRootElement.appendChild($oNewElement)
$oXML.save(@ScriptDir & "\test.xml")

oRootElement = ""

$oRootElement = $oXML.documentElement
Local $oComment = $oXML.createComment("test")
$oRootElement.appendChild($oComment)
$oXML.save(@ScriptDir & "\test.xml")

; User's COM error function. Will be called if COM error occurs
; Source: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/170063-how-to-use-selectnodes-on-xmldom/
Func _ErrFunc($oError)
    ConsoleWrite(@ScriptName & " (" & $oError.scriptline & ") : ==> COM Error intercepted !" & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.number is: " & @TAB & @TAB & "0x" & Hex($oError.number) & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.windescription:" & @TAB & $oError.windescription & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.description is: " & @TAB & $oError.description & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.source is: " & @TAB & @TAB & $oError.source & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.helpfile is: " & @TAB & $oError.helpfile & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.helpcontext is: " & @TAB & $oError.helpcontext & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.lastdllerror is: " & @TAB & $oError.lastdllerror & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.scriptline is: " & @TAB & $oError.scriptline & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.retcode is: " & @TAB & "0x" & Hex($oError.retcode) & @CRLF & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>_ErrFunc
```

**Update:** - added `createElement` example.